# How to extract values from column of mysql table having partial Json array values and remaining with string values

Tags: mysql, string, json-extract

[image: sample pic of mysql table]

Names of these 3 columns were Date, TargetName, Amount.
TargetName column has partial rows with json array values and remaining rows with strings.

I want to extract value[0] from json array.
With condition like [case when (targetName is Json type) Then $.value[0] else targetName]
How to apply this condition and get the expected result?

Expected outcome:
TargetName

SSC Stenographer

UP Police Sub Inspector

UPRVUNL JE

AAI JE Technical

ACC Exam

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN JSON_VALID(TargetName)
            THEN TargetName ->> "$[0].value"
            ELSE TargetName
            END AS TargetName ,
       ...
```

Comment: COALESCE function is not working for mysql server. Is there any alternative function for this please?

Comment: @HarikrishnaThummalapelly Well, conservative solution provided.

Comment: This is almost sorted. But these target names are stored as strings like 
"[{'language': 'English', 'value': 'West Bengal Group D'}, {'language': 'Hindi', 'value': 'West Bengal Group D'}]"

How to deal with this?

Comment: @HarikrishnaThummalapelly Provide a fiddle (or CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, 3-5 rows with and without JSON  **as formatted code**) and desired output, not as screenshot, into your question. And show desired output for provided source data.